# How to set different logging levels for vertx shadow jar in runtime?

Tags: java, log4j2, vert.x

vertx starter use shadow jar plugin to package a fat-jar

`log4j2.xml` will be put into the jar file

How can I run the jar with different log levels? (With springboot I can set `-Dspring.profile.active=test` to use `application-test.yml` for switch on debug logging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Log4j2 use another configuration file by setting the `log4j2.configurationFile` system property, as explained in the [configuration section](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) of the documentation:

```
java -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml -jar myapp.jar
```